# Magento2 : How to join table with where condition using getSelect()?

Tags: magento2, database, custom, uicomponent

I am new Magento 2.2.3.

I am trying to fetch data from custom table and display the same in **UI components**.
Everything will work but If I use where clause with **getSelect** then UI component will show "**We could not fetch any records**". If I use only **getselect** then it will work.

But for my requirement I have to use where clause.

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $seller_id = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('seller_id');

  $this->getSelect()->join(
        ['sales_order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
        'main_table.order_mage_id = sales_order.entity_id',
        '*'
    )->join(
        ['bo' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
        "bo.order_id = main_table.order_mage_id",
        '*'
    )->where('seller_id = ?', $seller_id)->group('main_table.id');;

}
```

This code I am using in

> **model\Resourcemodel\Mymodelname**

Any solution for this please.